# Second power supply detection

Tags: power-supply, detection

I have a power supply (5v) and I would like to detect when a second power supply of the same voltage (5v) is added to the circuit, the only idea that came to my mind is:

**My idea:**
To measure with the ADC of a microcontroller after a resistance between the first power supply (always connected) and a connector to add a second power supply.

The N-Mosfets are there to connect/disconnect the Resistance so it creates a voltage change without consuming energy when isn't needed

**What i tried**
I was reading about current sensors (hall and shunt types) but i didn't find something that suits this case (at least i didn't realized how)

**1. QUESTION:**
When the second power source is added, should the voltage drop be less? So it could be sensed by the ADC of the microcontroller.

**2. QUESTION**
There is another solution that can be made preferably through non invasive methods?

**3. QUESTION**
There is any way of knowing which power source is giving more power? or should i isolate them with diodes and have to use some current sensor?

Sorry if something is nonsense as I am self-taught and not good at electronics

Thanks for your time and efford

[image]

Comment: When you add the second power supply, where is that output connected in the circuit? Or if your schematic is showing the second supply, where does the first connect?

Comment: Connecting different power supplies in parallel can be hazardous. If your supplies don't explictly state that they support that, assume they don't.

Comment: InBedded16: The second power supply would connect to the coaxial connector right up side in the schema

Comment: jwsc: The idea is to detect when this happens so I can shut down one or the other

Comment: I'd use a power-path controller. Google them.

Comment: Andy aka: here it says that you should post as an answer so I can check that is a good one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer

Comment: Also thanks i was getting crazy with this thing